# How can I implementing post-redirect-get in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've been looking around for a solution implementing post-redirect-get on Rails. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865871/post-redirect-get-pattern-in-rails) suggests to use the flash, but it doesn't seem convincing. Is there a better way?

Comment: Could you point out why "it doesn't seem convincing"? This information may help people write an answer that fits you better. I personally don't see why that solution is not convincing.

Answer (score 0):

The flash is basically the same as using a session. You need a way to maintain submitted values if you're going to redirect. The only other ways to do that besides sessions (as far as I can see) are cookies or URL parameters. You might as well use the flash.